# How to block Same-origin policy to load same domain in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to load an URL from my own domain dynamically in an Iframe (or object -- I tried both), but it only works with external URLs. When I pass relative href (or from my own domain), It's rendered directly in the DOM. This breaks a series of patterns in the app's modal behavior.

```
$('a.external').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".modal-content").html('<object type="text/html" data="+'url'+" ></object>');
});
```

I'd like pass some params to say that I don't want to render in the main DOM even if it's the same origin. Does someone had this issue before?

Comment: I've manage to solve my problem using $.load(), but I still does not know how to make the iframe from same origin.

Comment: I've created a test page to try to understand your question better (http://tonylampada.github.io/randomstuff/iframeteste.html) but it seems I still don't :-) Can you provide a similar sample page to better explain what you want to do?